# How does a UISegmentedControl resize its content images?

Tags: ios, uiimage, autolayout, scale, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm having a bit of trouble setting images for the segments in a `UISegmentedControl`. I believe it only occurs when setting oversized images (that exceed the bounds of a segment) and I know a proper solution would be to use fitting images in the first place. However, I observed a strange resizing behaviour with those big images that I would like to understand:

These are two screenshots of the same `UISegmentedControl`. The only difference is that I use different images for their segments.

---

[image: Segmented Control with oversized square image]
[image: Segmented Control with oversized non-square image]

---

I color-coded the control components like this:

- Yellow: Segment separator
- Black: Segment background

As you can see some segment images are always horizontally distorted. In the first example with the happy smiley the inner two images appear with the correct aspect ratio whereas the to outer images are squeezed. In the second example with the anguished smiley the outer images appear with the correct aspect ratio whereas the inner two images are stretched.

Apparently iOS handles the inner and outer segment images differently. Does anyone know why this is the case? Under which conditions does iOS squeeze or stretch a segment image?